# My Time Machine backups are missing, though space is already used

Tags: backup, time-machine

I have this old 128GB SSD I found lately and decided to use it for my Time Machine backups. I connected it to my mac, it shows up properly, and I formatted it for Time Machine.

I finished my first backup on it, but the "Time Machine finished its first backup" massage is not showing up.

Then I found that my backup disk shows empty. Normally I would see my backup files in it, but it's got nothing in it. I checked if it's hidden but it's not either.

I finally found that the disk shows as read-only (by ⌘I), but I can't do anything to change that. On other folders, there is a list of users with access of that folder, but it only says read-only, and that's all I get.

However, on disk utility it shows that the drive has filled up (40GB) and I'm pretty sure that's the amount of backups I have.

Is there something wrong with my SSD? Is it because of some settings?

[image]
It's an APFS disk right now, but it didn't work with other types like MacOS Extended (Journaled) too.

Comment: Can you plug your external SSD add to your question the results (text) of the terminal command : `diskutil list external`

Comment: @Jean_JD Edited my question. I tried formatting it on a windows device and plugging it back, and it worked but it goes back to read-only when I set up time machine again.

Comment: The enclosure had a usb 2.0 interface, so I tried a Y cable. But that didn't work.

Comment: What's your internal disk capacity and usage? 128 Go it's very very small for a backup Time Machine. The new TM organization from Big Sur with APFS structure has modify the traditional usage of TM. But you always use a JHFS+ format for the TM saves : https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/types-of-disks-you-can-use-with-time-machine-mh15139/mac. Il you want see what's inside this disk, the command `ls -l /Volumes/BACKUP/*`

Comment: @Jean_JD I used 30GB of storage (and no one believes me). It's a SATA2 SSD I found somewhere inside my house, and connected to a USB 2.0 SATA inclosure. It's actually not that surprising to find that disk broken.

Comment: @Jean_JD zsh: no matches found: /Volumes/BACKUP/*

Comment: Oh great. Now it's stuck at "waiting to complete first backup" forever.

Comment: If you format APFS or JHFS+ this dive and don't use it with TM, that's work?

Comment: @Jean_JD Yes, it does. The problem only occurs in TM.

Comment: Ok. What is the physical size of the internal disk? Maybe it's a problem for tm using a small disk. Have you try formatting this ssd jhfs+ and after use it with tm?

Comment: @Jean_JD it's not a problem with the disk. I tried it on a 2TB HDD and it doesn't work either. The drive is filled up but it shows as empty.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems like the new cleaning option by system preferences in macOS Monterey isn't that stable. I recently reset my mac with it, and it probably messed it up with my older backups.

I just reset my mac the "traditional" way (via Disk Utility) and everything works fine (except it somehow changed my default language to English, but it doesn't matter). Turns out the original way takes longer (3h) but it does a way better job!